# Duda en estructura de datos Pilas

Tags: c++, pilas

Tengo una duda con ejercicio de pilas que encontré, en dicho ejercicio,se busca cuántas veces se repite una letra y  devuelve también el numero de letras que están en una posición par.

Tengo varias dudas, una de ellas es en esta parte:

¿qué están haciendo ahí?

```
while(!pila.empty()){
                             par=!par;//por cada letra pasa a ser impar, par
                             pila.pop();
                         }
```

¿Que se quiere hacer con la instrucción `par=!par` y luego con `pila.pop();`?

```
bool letrapar (char palabra[], char letra, stack_l_t<char> pila){
                     bool par=true;
                     int i=0;
                     int l=strlen(palabra);
                     while(i<l){
                        if(letra==palabra[i])
                            pila.push(palabra[i]);//meto las letras que busco en la pila, o eso entiendo

                        i++;
                     }
                     while(!pila.empty()){
                         par=!par;//por cada letra pasa a ser impar, par
                         pila.pop();
                     }
                    return par; 
                }
```

Comment: Tienes muchas preguntas sin respuetas aceptadas. podrias revisarlas y aceptar respuestas de aquellas que tengas respuestas correctas? Es importante para mantener el sitio ordenado y ayudar a otros que tengan consultas similares. Gracias.

Comment: `¿Que se quiere hacer con la instrucción par=!par y luego con pila.pop();?``bool letrapar (char palabra[], char letra, stack_l_t<char> pila){` Deberías explicarte primero qué es un stack_l_t; yo creo que con eso como primer paso ya sabrás preguntar algo con sentido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>En ningún lado este ejercicio busca ver la cantidad de veces que se repite una letra.</strike>

Este ejercicio solo usa un método complicado (con una pila, bah) para saber si <strike>la cantidad de letras que tiene la palabra es par o impar</strike> una determinada letra se repite una cantidad par o impar de veces dentro de la palabra.

```
while(i<l){
    if(letra==palabra[i])
        pila.push(palabra[i]);//meto las letras que busco en la pila, o eso entiendo
    i++;
}
```

El codigo de arriba inserta en la pila solo las letras que son iguales a la letra que recibio por parametro.

`par=!par` como `par` es una variable `booleana`, hace que la misma se transforme a su contrario, o sea si es `true` pasa a `false`, y si es `false` para a `true`

y `pila.pop()` , como ya te conteste hace un rato, saca el elemento de la pila que sigue (que siempre es el primero).

```
while(!pila.empty()){
    par=!par;//por cada letra pasa a ser impar, par
    pila.pop();
}
```

Y este codigo, va sacando de la pila y cambiando el valor de `par` entre `true` y `false`

Comment: y por qué hace esto if(letra==palabra[i])?

Comment: tenes razon.. no lei todo el codigo (o no lo entendi bien). ahora actualizo la respuesta)

Comment: @AER e igual te pediria que revises todas las preguntas que ya hiciste y aceptes las respuestas en los casos donde ellas te ayudaron, o pidas aclaraciones en los casos en los cuales las necesitas.

Comment: Hola, con qué fin se va sacando de la pila y cambiando el valor?

Comment: while(!pila.empty()){
    par=!par;//por cada letra pasa a ser impar, par
    pila.pop()
}

Comment: esa es la duda que tengo @gbianchi

Comment: va sacando de la pila, para ver cuantas letras metio en la pila, y saber si la cantidad es par o impar...

Comment: ok, entonces solo va a hacer un pop de las letras que efectivamente se encuentran en la palabra  no?  pero cómo el programa se va a dar cuenta de que la cantidad de repeticiones es par o impar? disculpa que me reitere, no se si es que soy nuevo en esto, pero no entiendo "par=!par como par es una variable booleana, hace que la misma se transforme a su contrario, o sea si es true pasa a false, y si es false para a true", supongo que esa parte se encarga de hacer eso, pero a lo mejor yo no lo entiendo, si me lo podrías explicar con un ejemplo cotidiano o algo para entenderlo. Gracias

Comment: eso iba a preguntarte

Comment: no aparece tu etiqueta

Comment: esa es otra duda que tengo @gbianchi

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62601/discussion-between-gbianchi-and-aer).

Comment: Ve al chat.. porque no termino de entender tus dudas..